# Is it possible to generify this function?

Tags: java, generics, covariance

I'm having trouble creating this generic function due to co-variance rules in Java.  I understand that I can use wildcards and do `List<? extends/super T>`.  I just cant see how it is applicable to this situation.

---

- If I want to pass in a `dataItems` and an`Iterable<DataItem>` here, I am not allowed because they do not match type `IInterface` and collections are not co-variant.
- If I change `Map<String, List<IInterface>> target` to `<? extends IInterface>` then I cannot call `items.add(x);` at the bottom for obvious reasons.
- If I change it to `<? super IInterface>` then the function is happy, but I cannot call it with the `dataItems` variable because `DerivedClass` is not a super class of IInterface.
- I can properly use

---

```
//DerivedClass implements IInterface which provides getId().
private Map<String, List<DerivedClass>> dataItems; 
private Map<String, List<OtherDerivedClass>> otherDataItems; 

private void populate(Map<String, List<IInterface>> target,
         Iterable<? extends IInterface> source) {
    for (final IInterface x : source) {
        List<IInterface> items = target.get(x.getId());
        if (items == null) target.put(x.getId(),
            new ArrayList<IInterface>(){{add(x);}});
        else items.add(x);
    }
}
```

---

**Question:** How could I modify this function so that it will be effective, or how should I change my basic design here?

Comment: `private <T extends IInterface> void popupate(..., Iterable<T>)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried declaring a generic type parameter for the whole method? Something like:

```
private <I extends IInterface> void populate(Map<String, List<I>> target, Iterable<I> source)
```

Comment: This seems closer... but if I do this, new ArrayList<I>(){{add(x);}}); fails as I cannot add tot he list.  items.add(x) also fails.

Comment: @w00te, If I understand you, I've addressed this in my answer.

Comment: Okay, so this solution works with one caveat.  I have to directly cast {X} in my adds to I like: add((I)x); and items.add((I)x);  Is this okay to do?

Answer (score 1):

Building on @fge and @Ray suggestion, after you generify the function, you can call it with any type you need, such as with

```
<IInterface>populate(...)
```

Normally this syntax is used with static functions

```
ClassName.<Type>getWhatever(...);
```

but there's nothing to stop you from doing it non-statically.

Also, if you do generify the function, you'll need to generify everything in it to reflect that bound. Meaning something like this

```
private <I extends IInterface> void populate(Map<String, List<I>> target,
         Iterable<I> source) {
    for (final I x : source) {
        List<I> items = target.get(x.getId());
        if (items == null) target.put(x.getId(),
            new ArrayList<I>(){{add(x);}});
        else items.add(x);
    }
}
```

More information: http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-generics-java-%E2%80%93

Comment: +1 as this is interesting, but in this situation when I put the extra type parameter intelliJ tells me that it's not required, it can infer the type from the usage.  Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I'm surprised by that. We both learned something. Thanks for the up-vote. :)